# Pico CMS Magazine Theme issues

Tags: php, content-management-system, flat-file

Please, I tried to integrate a CMS theme Pico called magazine from here https://github.com/BesrourMS/magazine. I follow the procedure github but without success . I put the template in the theme folder. I create a content file and I included index.md and page.md template .
I edit config.php by writing the name of the theme and changing the **$config [ ' content_dir '] = ' content- sample/** ' by **$config [ ' content_dir '] = ' content/ ';** 
I got this in my directory :

- composer.json
- composer.lock
- config
- content
- content-sample
- index.php
- lib
- plugins
- themes
- twig
- vendor

But it's still the theme that appears by default. and when i add something in the directory folder nothing appear on Atom is that normal ?
Did someone would have an idea? please.

Please no one know Pico CMS ?

Answer (score 1):

It appears, you never actually activated the theme.
Try putting this line in your config file:

```
$config['theme'] = 'magazine';
```

Comment: thank you in fact it's working... sorry for the latest answer ! thanks a lot !